Pressure/velocity increase in fluid via pump
I've been trying to read up on pumps and their application of Bernoulli's equation with some extra head terms. However, there's something I can't reason through and that is: how do we know the amount of work done by the pump that will go into increasing the fluid velocity and the amount of work done by the pump that will go into increasing the pressure?
In case of a pump pushing a fluid into a closed tank with no outlet, obviously the velocity is zero and the pressure alone must increase. Alternatively, if the inlet and outlet are completely open to atmosphere then the pump pushing the fluid will serve to only increase its velocity. But what about in-between?
(1) What mathematical relations are needed to describe how much of the pump work will go into increasing the velocity vs increasing the pressure?
(2) Practically, what downstream components would regulate the downstream pressure/velocity (i.e. how can you modulate the amount of energy that goes into changing the velocity or the pressure)?
Specifically I have a situation in which I have a constraint for the flow velocity at the outlet (i.e. I know what it must be). If I use this velocity to derive a flow rate and I use this flow rate to determine the head of the pump (using a performance curve), can I guarantee that any additional head will go into raising the pressure (or overcoming friction/head losses) and not into raising the velocity?

The characteristics of pump response as a function of volume throughput, pressure difference, and pump speed must be determined experimentally.
